# Storing raw xml data with stax without parsing

Tags: java, xml, stax

Can anyone provide me information on how to store raw xml with java stax?  Their is plenty of information available on how to parse the xml with stax, but is it possible to capture the actual xml data based on a tag name or root element?  For example, if the below xml comes in, how can I store it in as a string exactly how it came in?

```
<xmlData><name>Bob</name></xmlData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. There are character encodings and entity expansions going on, why you cannot be sure of the actual "raw" XML. You can re-create the XML to be semantically equal, but not necessarily equal byte for byte.

But why would you? The parsers are there to shield you from all those gory details. If you really need the raw stuff, read the byte stream.